# In jq, how to select objects where an array contains at least one value (intersection non-empty)

Tags: json, select, jq, any

I have input like this:

```
{ "prop": ["apple", "banana"] }
{ "prop": ["kiwi", "banana"] }
{ "prop": ["cherry", "orange"] }
```

How do I print objects where prop contains at least one of kiwi and orange?

(The list of interesting values is longer than just 2, so I'd like to leverage the `any` function somehow.)

I've tried the following

```
jq 'select(any(.prop[] | contains(["kiwi", "orange"])))' < input.json
```

and various variants of the above, but can't figure out the right expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream-oriented version of the built-in function `any` can be most easily used if one bears in mind its signature:

```
def any(generator; condition):
```

So we are led to:

```
select( any( .prop[]; . == "kiwi" or . == "orange" ))
```

or more succinctly:

```
select( any(.prop[]; IN("kiwi", "orange")))
```

### whitelist

If the values of interest are provided as a JSON array, say $whitelist, you could tweak the above by substituting `$whitelist[]` for the explicit stream of values:

```
select( any(.prop[]; IN($whitelist[]) ))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`IN/2`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators). It's [implemented using `any`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/a17dd3248a666d01be75f6b16be37e80e20b0954/src/builtin.jq#L275), but is far easier to grasp.

```
select(IN(.prop[]; "kiwi", "orange"))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bB3UfjOGs4)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The above answers worked for me in jq 1.7, but they failed in jq 1.6 (which is what's preinstalled on a GitHub Actions ubuntu-latest runner in February 2024, and I don't want the performance hit of installing something better during every CI run).

Here's what I came up with that works correctly and consistently in both 1.6 and 1.7:

```
def intersects(a; b):
  any(a[] as $aElem | b | index($aElem));
```

Use as follows:

```
intersects(["a", "b", "c"]; ["c", "d", "e"]) # true
```

or

```
intersects(["a", "b", "c"]; ["d", "e", "f"]) # false
```